# How insert value qty in custom var?

Tags: magento-1.9

i dont know how make a function with custom var for getQty for use in my custom message. My block code:

```
 
class Sc_StockMessages_Block_Messages extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {
    public function getMessage(){
    $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
    $quantity=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
    if($quantity<= Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty')) { 
    echo Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_message')  . intval($quantity) . " ";
```

And my custom phtml is...:

```
$stockQty = $this->getMessage();
```

```
    echo $this->__($stockQty);
```

My result is: `The stock is below than %s items 10` (i want to make the value 10 associate with the var %s, how i can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want put variable to message, try do it that way:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$qty = array();
$qty[] = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()
$message = vsprintf(Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_message'), $qty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something here you can play around with in the view;

```
<?php 
$inventoryQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>

        <?php if ($inventoryQty <= 10): ?>

                <div class="availability out-of-stock">
                    <span>
                    The stock is below than <?php echo $inventoryQty ?> items
                    </span>
                </div>

            <?php else: ?>
                    <span>
                    IN STOCK
                    </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: My message is writed direct in admin backend from text and called from this block, is not possible to use message writed in code..

Comment: Ah, I totally miss read the question.